# Excel Automation - Refresh Excel Plugin Data with pyautogui

Tags: python, excel, pyautogui

My team has built out excel workbooks that is pulling data from an excel plugin (Haver). In order to refresh Haver within the excel, there is a shortcut "ctrl + d". I want Python to automatically refresh the Haver data in the excel workbook via the "ctrl + d" shortcut. Below is the python code I have built so far. The excel opens, makes a chime noise (i'm assuming which is replicating the ctrl d) closes, and saves but the actual data is not refreshing.. can someone help explain why the goal to refresh the Haver data is not working as expected?

```
import time
import openpyxl
import pyautogui
import win32com.client

from win32gui import SetForegroundWindow
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("GDP_Deflator.xlsx")
xl.Visible = True
SetForegroundWindow(xl.Hwnd)
time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.hotkey(['ctrl','d'], interval=1)
time.sleep(3)

workbook.save('GDP_Deflator.xlsx')
workbook.close()
```

Expecting the excel plugin (Haver) data to automatically refresh using the "ctrl + d" shortcut via python pyautogui

Comment: Why do you open the Excel workbook with Openpyxl and not Win32com? Openpyxl is not going to refresh/update the sheet it doesn't use Excel and cannot perform that task.